# Work done by a vector field along a curve

Tags: integration, vector-fields

I have to find the work done by a vector field $\vec{F}$ along a curve $C$ from $t = 0$ to $t = 1$:

$$
\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (2xe^y + 2x)\vec{i} + (x^2e^y)\vec{j} + (3z^2)\vec{k}
\\
C: \;\vec{r}(t) = f(t)\vec{i} + g(t)\vec{j} + h(t)\vec{k} = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\vec{i} + (t-t^3)\vec{j} + \frac{2}{1+t^2}\vec{k}
$$

Formula:

$$
W = \int_a^b \vec{F}(f(t), g(t), h(t)) \cdot \vec{r}\;'(t) \; \operatorname d\!t
$$

I got

$$
\;\vec{r}\;'(t) = f(t)'\vec{i} + g(t)'\vec{j} + h(t)'\vec{k} = \frac{-2(t^2-1)}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{i} + (1-3t^2)\vec{j} + \frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{k}
\\
\vec{F}(f(t), g(t), h(t)) = \frac{4t(1+e^{t-t^3})}{1+t^2}\vec{i} + (\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^2e^{t-t^3}\vec{j} + \frac{12}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{k}
$$

So I have to evaluate this integral

$$
W = \int_0^1 \vec{F}(f(t), g(t), h(t)) \cdot \vec{r}\;'(t) \; \operatorname d\!t
\\
W = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{4t(1+e^{t-t^3})}{1+t^2}\vec{i} + (\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^2e^{t-t^3}\vec{j} + \frac{12}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{k}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{-2(t^2-1)}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{i} + (1-3t^2)\vec{j} + \frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2}\vec{k}\right) \; \operatorname d\!t
\\
W = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{4t(1+e^{t-t^3})}{1+t^2}\frac{-2(t^2-1)}{(1+t^2)^2} + (\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^2e^{t-t^3}(1-3t^2) + \frac{12}{(1+t^2)^2}\frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2}\right)\; \operatorname d\!t
$$

I am supposed to do it by hand. It means that I must've missed something, but I don't know what! If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your vector field seems to be a gradient field...

Comment: @fixedp What does this imply?

Does it mean that I have to find $f$ so that $\vec{F} = \nabla f$, and then $W = \int_a^b \vec{F}(f(t), g(t), h(t)) \cdot \vec{r}\;'(t) \; \operatorname d\!t = f(a) - f(b)$ ?

Comment: It means the work done is independent of the path taken: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct, although the right hand side should read $f(r(b))-f(r(a))$

Comment: Oh, yes, I kind of messed that up! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force you have given is a conservative one, which means that there exists a function $U(\vec{r})$ such that $\vec{F}=-\nabla U$, where minus sign is here for convention. In this case you have

$$W=\int\limits_{A}^{B}\vec{F}d\vec{r}=-\int\limits_{A}^{B}\nabla U d\vec{r} = -\int\limits_{A}^{B}dU=U(A)-U(B)$$

The potential $U$ in your example can be found by straigtforward integration of components of $\vec{F}$.